# str.format("%s, blah..", output) was work fine in vc++6.0, but why not work in vc++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm feel so sorry for this simple stupid question, but it repeatedly appearing in my book, almost drive me to crazy ;-(

I'm learn API/MFC, book is based on VC++ 6.0, but my VS version is 2010, 'cos of the version difference I don't know how to fix it to matching vc++ 2010:

```
...
CString str;
str.Format("%s, blah...", whatever.output);
...
```

I have both vc++6.0 & vc++ 2010 installed, sample code running fine in vc++6.0, but won't work in vc++2010, some says cast to (LPCTSTR) is the solution, but

```
str.Format("%s, blah...", (LPCTSTR)whatever.output);
```

still not work!

Do I missing something important? but what should I do?

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: We can't help you without more information. What type is `whatever.output`? Is it Unicode project? What is the example input, expected output, and actual output? Give more code. Give us a complete code that we can copy-paste in our Visual Studio and see the problem that you have.

Comment: Please define "it does not work". Does it compile or not ? Does it crash ? Does it produce another output than expected ? Or... ?

Comment: Ooops! thank you  Dialecticus & Michael Walz, you gave me a good hint, to unset the unicode, it pass the compilation. 

BTW, by book on hand didn't give me a clear hint about the unicode...

Your reply saved much much of my life time, thanks again!

Comment: So it was a compiler error, and there was a text in build output in effect saying that first parameter of `Format` call cannot be converted from `const char*` to `const wchar_t*`. This text is much more important than generic "it doesn't work" comment. Next time post this text from build output.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments it seems that it was a compiler error, because the project was set to Unicode. You avoided the error by setting the project to non-Uncode, but to fix the error so that it compiles in both Unicode and non-Unicode configurations you should envelope all [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) with `_T` macro, like this:

```
str.Format(_T("%s, blah..."), whatever.output);
//         ^^^_____________^  <-- add this
```